# Value of $(this) lost from select box when using Chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have written my own custom form validation for one of our client's sites which runs onChange, onfocusout and onSubmit.

The following function calls the validation for select boxes:

```
    $("fieldset select").change(function(){
        changeCircumstance.validate(true, $(this)); 
    });
```

I am passing through the ID of the form item to be validated using "$(this)" and a value of true to indicate that this will be onChange validation.

I am using the Chosen plugin on this site and have noticed that my validation runs perfectly on most form elements but not on select box elements. I believe this is caused by the select boxes being changed by Chosen into div tags which then cannot return the $(this) value which is required by my validation.

How can I target a particular Chosen select box on change in order to display an error message in the correct place, etc without the use of $(this)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("fieldset select").chosen().change(...)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to have made any difference I'm afraid. I still get an empty object returned when trying to access the value passed into the function.

Comment: Does this plugin have a callback function for when all content is loaded?